# Chrome Webstore images appear blurry when uploaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension, image-resizing, chrome-web-store

When I upload images to the chrome web store as promotional images (appears to work fine for small tiles large and marquee sizes) they become unreasonably blurry. As they give two options (1280x800 size or 640x400 size) i have tried both but to no avail.
For example:

Original image as a png and with size 1280x800:
[image]

After uploading and submitted:
[image]

I discovered that the 640x400 size works slightly better than the 1280x80 (no idea why) but it is still unreasonably blurry. This is the highest quality photoshop can export, and I tried creating it in adobe XD - same issue.

For reference this is the 1280x800 blurriness
[image]

Any ideas as to how I can fix this? Because it looks really bad and quite unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do anything about that. Even their own Web Store products (like [Keep](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-chrome-extens/lpcaedmchfhocbbapmcbpinfpgnhiddi)) have blurry images. At least they all look blurry on 5K iMac screen.

Just the way they are converting images on their own.

I assume you did, but did you try to run your image through [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com) compression before upload? Just in case the image is too large for their standards, and they execute compression on it.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Store serves a 640x400 version regardless of what size you upload and is generating that smaller version on the fly, all because of the query-string `=w640-h400` in the `src` (try modifying it to `=w1280-h800` and see how much better it could be).